# how to change the look of the scheduler control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

hii

I am using devexpress xtrascheduler.in that am having a scheduler which is having the default look(having time in the left side verticaly)but  i have to get some labels on the left side ie,in addition to the existing scheduler control look...

In simple i want to add some label on the existing scheduler control verticaly.is it possible..help me please..

Comment: I do not quite understand what you need to achieve, please post a link to whata screenshot showing the desired look and feel.

Comment: actually i want to know about the resource sharing..how the reources are added?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off asking this question [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question) or [here](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/173.aspx).